# How do you trigger a push when a specific directory in a branch gets an update?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want my workflow to trigger on a push only if there are changes made to a specific directory. Is this possible, what am I missing? I tried doing something like what you see below, but it didn't fire the trigger.

```
name: ABC

on:
  push:
    branches:  [master/my-directory]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

`push` has a property called [`paths`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore):

```yaml
name: ABC
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    paths:
      - my-directory/**
```

This will only trigger on pushes to the `master` branch with changes in the `my-directory` directory tree. See the [filter pattern cheat sheet](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#patterns-to-match-file-paths) for all possible filter patterns.

Comment: how to make it work for all future branches?

Comment: @Masmoudi I think you can just drop the `branches:` list and it should trigger on every branch.

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: I though this setup would trigger on both events: "a change on the files in my-directory/" OR  "any push on master branch". Are you saying that this will trigger only if "the files in my-directory/ changed" AND "it happened on the master branch" ?

Comment: @Florian Pretty sure it's logical AND for the conditions, but not 100% – docs aren't explicit as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Florian Hmm, after looking at docs, I'm inclined to think it's OR. Let me test that so I can amend the answer. It's definitely OR for the top-level triggers.

Comment: @Florian Confirmed behaviour: top-level triggers are OR, so if you have `on:` and then both `schedule:` and `push:`, either will trigger the workflow. Which makes sense. Within a trigger, like `push:`, the additional criteria for `branches:` and `paths:` are AND. Now, I'm not 100% sure about `branches:` and `tags:`, but for the purposes of the answer here, the statement "pushes to the `master` branch with changes in the `my-directory` directory tree" is correct.

Comment: @BenjaminW, what if I want this for both - `push` and `pull request`? Do i need to copy `paths` to `pull request` as well or there is a more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: @Superbman Pretty sure you have to copy those, since they refer only to `push` and `pull_request` separately.