# Committing specific changes on gh-pages branch via a GitHub action that triggers on pushes to master

Tags: r, github-actions

I have two branches in a repository which contains an R package:

- the 'master' branch,
- and a 'gh-pages' branch, from where the documentation website for the package is hosted.

Whenever there is a commit to master changing any of the R files present in the `R/` folder, (i.e. `tree/master/R/*.R`) I would like to push those changes to the gh-pages branch via GitHub Actions. (these R files are used to generate the `man` files which in turn create the documentation) I wouldn't like to push changes other than those involving a change in `R/` directory, since they are irrelevant for the purpose of generating the documentation.

How can we update such changes on a gh-pages branch (or any other branch) via a GitHub Action which triggers on pushes to the master branch, considering only commits for the R files within the `R/` directory? Could someone show an example of a `.yaml` file introducing such a workflow?

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: There are two actions for gh-pages that might help you: 1) https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages. 2) https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-github-pages

The second seems to give a .ymal example that correspond to what you want to do.

Comment: @GuiFalourd Thanks! I looked at both and I actually dropped by the second one yesterday, and yes it does the job for committing all the files to gh-pages branch on pushes to master. However, I don't know if we can specifically select some files or a directory to commit to the gh-pages branch. Do you know how to commit only changes to a particular file or directory? (among changes in a commit which involve other files/folders too)

Comment: You can specify in your workflow.yml file which directory to watch to trigger your workflow, there is an example in this stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63460875/github-actions-how-do-you-trigger-a-push-when-a-specific-directory-in-a-branch (the example is with a push but you can use with other options as well).

Comment: @GuiFalourd Thanks! exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Great! I'll post it as official answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two actions for gh-pages that might help you:

1. [github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages](http://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages)
2. [github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-github-pages](http://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-github-pages)

The second gives a .yaml example that correspond to what you want to do.

Moreover, you can specify in your `workflow.yaml` file which directory to watch to trigger your workflow.

There is an example in this stackoverflow question: [Github Actions - How do you trigger a push when a specific directory in a branch gets an update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63460875/github-actions-how-do-you-trigger-a-push-when-a-specific-directory-in-a-branch)

(This example is with a `push` but you can use with other options as well)