# GitHub Actions - How to trigger a run on push to branch A OR push to specific path in branch B

Tags: github, github-actions

[From another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63461325/2493756) I know how to run an action if an update is pushed to (a specific path in) a certain branch. The answer also implies how to run an action on any update in a specific branch.

However, what I would like is to trigger an update

- either a push to any file/folder in branch A
- or a push to a specific file in branch B

I have tried the following, but that throws a syntax error (because it seems there can only be one `push` entry):

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - translation-files
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - .github/workflows/translation-updates-to-main-repo.yml
```

Any idea if such combination would be possible, and if so: how? (If not, I'll probably have to just accept to manually initiate the run in case I update this action workflow.)

Comment: You can't achieve what you want using the `on` field alone (except if you use more than one workflow file). However, you could evaluate the `branch ref` and if the specific path has been updated in a job step (there is an interesting [path filter action](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) for that). Then, based on the result, you could check if you want to perform the update or not in further steps/jobs. All in the same workflow file.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you put it as an answer, I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve what you want using the `on` field alone (except if you use more than one workflow file, one for each trigger).

However, you could evaluate the `branch ref` and if the specific path has been updated in a job step (there is an interesting [path filter action](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) for that). Then, based on the result/output, you could check if you want to perform the update or not in further steps/jobs. All in the same workflow file.